# C++ multiline CString literal in VS2013 Unicode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unicode

A multiline CString literal 'str1', accepted without a wink in VS2012 (with MBCS) is now refused at build time, after upgrading to VS2013 (with Unicode, to alleviate tons of errors from the newly deprecated MBCS, even after installing its addon), with the output message:

> error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings

as in the following example (A):

```
str1 = _T("     HELP - available commands \n\n\n"
          "F1    :   the present help message \n\n");
```

The first line is reported 'wide' and the second 'narrow'.

I have then tried (B) to add mono-line CString literals:

```
str1 =   _T("     HELP - available commands \n\n\n")
       + _T("F1    :   the present help message \n\n");
```

but the IDE already complains with

> Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

and the builder with

> error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers

It does indeed work if I build (C) the CString str1 with mono-line literals one by one:

```
str1  = _T("     HELP - available commands \n\n\n");
str1 += _T("F1    :   the present help message \n\n");
```

but I would like to understand why (A) and (B) do not work here, as expected, and as they were so until now. There are several such problems in this (large) program, but in most other similar instances it does work just fine.

Is it due to changes in VS2013 or (and?) the switch from MBCS to Unicode? Are there special characters I overlooked in these strings? And then, how to fix these problems?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Try (B) without the `+`.

Comment: Thanks. Example (B) does work without the '+' but it adds overhead compared to (A). And why was (A) working before and is not anymore?

Comment: @hpb it does not add overhead - it is just like saying L"..." L"..." which concatenates the constants at compile time.

Comment: What you had before wasn't a multi-line literal by the way (you could do that with a backslash at the end of the line, but that's pretty horrible). You had two adjacent string literals, which are automatically concatenated. And after the fix that's what you have again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
str1  = _T("     HELP - available commands \n\n\n") // no semicolon here
        _T("F1    :   the present help message \n\n");
```

The reason it worked before is that _T is a no-op for MBCS but for Unicode expands to a width prefix. In C/C++ concatenation is just by making them adjacent with whitespace, but they need the same prefix, at least for MSVC.

Comment: No, in neither C nor in C++ is the same prefix required. It's only MSVC that requires that. (But having the same prefix is perfectly valid in standard C and C++ too, so no problem with your recommendation.)

Comment: In C99 - "Whether differently-prefixed wide string literal tokens can be concatenated and, if so, the treatment of the resulting multibyte character sequence are implementation-defined."

Comment: @hvd - I did not know that! Sure enough according to the standard in both C and C++ a mixture of prefix and no prefix is treated as both having the same prefix. Differing prefixes are either illegal or implementation defined. So is MSVC non-compliant here? Thanks for pointing this out, I'll tune up my answer.

Comment: @Anders: "Implementation defined" means the documentation must state whether it's supported. Since [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) states it's not supported (error C2308), MSVC++ is behaving as defined and in the clear.

Comment: @MSalters No, as Anders pointed out, concatenating two string literals, where both have a prefix, but the prefix is different, that's implementation-defined. Concatenating two string literals where one has a prefix but the other doesn't, that's perfectly valid, MSVC is wrong to reject valid programs. See C++14 [lex.string]p14, but it's the same in other versions of the standard as far as I know.

Comment: @hvd: Oh, misunderstanding. The linked example shows 2 differing prefixes, `U"" L""` which generates C2308. The `L"wide" "narrow"` case is introduced by [N1653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1653.htm). This isn't supported even in [VS2015}(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx), see note 4. It's a C99 preprocessor feature.

Comment: @MSalters I did check C++ 2011 too and it is there. But not in C++2003. Guess MSVC is not very current. Their table doesn't say: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable

Comment: I don't understand why VS2013 wants to have so much fun with this, but I think I'll just call it a bug.  The first two compile, the third generates C2308.  Microsoft, what part of OPEN PARENTHESIS isn't clear to you?
                ErrorExit(TEXT("SetupDiCallClassInstaller")TEXT(" 813"));
                ErrorExit((LPTSTR) ("SetupDiCallClassInstaller" " 813"));
                ErrorExit(TEXT("SetupDiCallClassInstaller" " 813"));